# auto suggection select using keyboard in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a auto suggest in which i can select using mouse but i do need to select them using key board.

How do i do it? can i do it using javascript?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout jquery-ui's autocomplete [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

Answer (score 0):

use keydown event before autocomplete

```
.bind( "keydown", function( event ){
                if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                        $( this ).data("autocomplete").menu.active ) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                }
            })
            .autocomplete({
```

here on tab press it will be selected

Comment: function lookup(inputString) {
  if(inputString.length == 0) {
   // Hide the suggestion box.
   $('#suggestions').hide();
  } else {
   $.post("rpc.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data){
    if(data.length >0) {
    
     $('#suggestions').show();
     $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
     
    }
   });
  }
  
  
  
 }     Hi harish am using this coding. where should i implement that(your) coding